# Is it a stochastic matrix?

Tags: code-golf, matrix

A [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) is a matrix of probabilities used in the context of Markov chains.

A *right* stochastic matrix is a matrix where each row sums to `1`.

A *left* stochastic matrix is a matrix where each column sums to `1`.

A *doubly* stochastic matrix is a matrix where each row and each column sums to `1`.

In this challenge, we will represent the probabilities **in percent using integers**. A row or column must in that case sum to `100` and not `1`.

**Your goal** is to write a program or function which, given a square matrix of integers as input, outputs one of four values indicating that the matrix is either right stochastic, left stochastic, doubly stochastic or none of those.

#### Input

You may use any proper representation of a matrix that is natural for your language for the input. For example, a list of lists, a string of comma separated values with rows separated by linebreaks, etc.

The input matrix will always be square and will only contain non-negative integers. The input matrix will always be at least `1×1`.

You may pass the input using `STDIN`, as a function argument, or anything similar.

#### Output

You must choose **four distinct outputs** that correspond to *right stochastic*, *left stochastic*, *doubly stochastic* or *none of those*. Those outputs must be constant regardless of what input is passed. Your program may not return different outputs for the same case, e.g. saying that any negative number corresponds to *none of those* is not valid.

In short, there must be a 1-to-1 correspondence between your output an the four possible cases. Some examples of those four outputs would be `{1, 2, 3, 4}` or `{[1,0], [0,1], [1,1], [0,0]}` or even `{right, left, doubly, none}`.

Please indicate in your answer the four outputs your program uses.

If a matrix is doubly stochastic, then you must return the output corresponding to doubly stochastic, and not right or left stochastic.

You may print the output to `STDOUT`, return it from a function, or anything similar.

#### Test cases

```
[100]               => Doubly stochastic

[42]                => None of those

[100  0  ]          => Doubly stochastic
[0    100]

[4   8   15]
[16  23  42]        => Left stochastic
[80  69  43]

[99  1 ]            => Right stochastic
[2   98]

[1   2   3   4 ]
[5   6   7   8 ]    => None of those
[9   10  11  12]
[13  14  15  16]
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Can I take an input determining the size of the matrix first?

Comment: @AlexL. No, this would be unfair to change the specs at this point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Right stochastic:  `[0,1]`
Left stochastic:   `[1,0]`
Doubly stochastic: `[1,1]`
None of those:     `[0,0]`

```
Dø2FOTnQPˆ
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RMO4MkZPVG5RUMuG&input=W1s0LDgsMTVdLFsxNiwyMyw0Ml0sWzgwLDY5LDQzXV0)

**Explanation**

```
D            # duplicate input
 ø           # transpose the copy
  2F         # 2 times do (once for each matrix)
    O        # sum of the rows
     TnQ     # is equal to 100
        P    # product
         ˆ   # add to global list
             # implicitly print global list at the end of the program
```

Answer (score 15):

## Haskell, <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```
import Data.List
s a=all((==100).sum)<$>[transpose a,a]
```

Input of type `(Eq a, Num a) => [[a]]`. Outputs boolean list `[left-stochastic, right-stochastic]`

Thanks to @proudhaskeller for saving 2 bytes

Comment: Couldn't you save some bytes by making the function pointfree? e.g. with `[transpose,id]<*>` (then you could omit the `s a=` as anynomous functions are allowed)

Comment: @flawr possibly, but `[transpose,id]<*>` has a type of `[[[a]]]->[[[a]]]`, which needs another layer of `map` and a `pure`/`return`/`(:[])` or a input of type [[[Int]]], which isn't natural. Best I got is `map(all(==100).map sum).(<$>[transpose,id]).flip id`

Comment: Ah right, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: How about `all((==100).sum)` instead of `all(==100).map sum`?

Comment: @proudhaskeller of course! `all` does a mapping in itself.

Answer (score 11):

### R, 55 bytes

```
function(m)c(all(colSums(m)==100),all(rowSums(m)==100))
```

Unnamed function where `m` is assumed to be an R-matrix.

Output:

- `[1]  TRUE FALSE`: Left stochastic
- `[1]  FALSE TRUE`: Right stochastic
- `[1]  TRUE TRUE`: Doubly
- `[1]  FALSE FALSE`: None

Comment: `any(colSums(m)-100)` and likewise for the `rowSums` will drop you two bytes while inverting all the outputs, so if you'd like to keep those, you can always put a `!` in front for net `-1` byte.

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, <s>35</s> <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
@(n)any([sum(n);sum(n')]-100,2)
```

Call it like this:

```
f(100)
f(42)
f([4,8,15; 16,23,42; 80,69,43])
f([99,1;2,98])
f([1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16])
```

[**Test it here.**](https://ideone.com/ByF5r1)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to flawr initially, but went for another approach that was 1 byte shorter.

This outputs the following for the different cases:

```
0    Doubly
0    

1    None
1

0    Left
1

1    Right
0
```

The last `,2` would be unnecessary if single digits weren't included. Also, if this summed to `1` instead of `100` (as it could have), it would save another `4` bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## k, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
{min'100=+/'(x;+x)}
```

Output

- `00b` none
- `10b` left
- `01b` right
- `11b` both

Example:

```
k)f:{min'100=+/'(x;+x)} //store function as f
k)f(100 0;98 2)
01b
```

**edit:** reduce byte count by 3 - function does not need to be enclosed in a lambda

**edit:** reduce bytecount by 2 - H/T @Simon Major

Comment: You can actually save a byte by enclosing in a lambda: 
{min'100=+/'(x;+:x)}

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica 29 Bytes

```
{}⋃Tr/@#=={100}&/@{#,#}&
```

substituting the =U+F3C7=[\Transpose] character.  This code snippet will paste correctly into Mathematica.

Same truthiness convention with {lefttruth, righttruth} as output

Comment: `{}⋃` saves one byte over `Union@`

Comment: @ASimmons, thanks for the tip! Put it in and corrected an error in my byte total.

Comment: Also I think if you make your output {righttruth, lefttruth}, then replacing `Total@` with `Tr/@` will save a further 2 bytes.

Comment: Or equivalently reverse the two matrices so the solution becomes
`{}⋃Tr/@#=={100}&/@{#,#}&`

Comment: @ASimmons, Yes, that saved another 2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
sG!sv!100=XA
```

Output is two zero/one values. First indicates if the matrix is left-stochastic, second if it is right-stochastic.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=c0chc3YhMTAwPVhB&input=WzQgOCAxNTsgMTYgMjMgNDI7IDgwICA2OSAgNDNd) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YFhLCnNLIXN2ITEwMD1YQQpEVA&input=WzEwMF0KWzQyXQpbMTAwIDA7IDAgMTAwXQpbNCA4IDE1OyAxNiAyMyA0MjsgODAgIDY5ICA0M10KWzk5IDE7IDIgOThdClsxIDIgMyA0OyA1IDYgNyA4OyA5IDEwIDExIDEyOyAxMyAxNCAxNSAxNl0)

```
s      % Implicitly input N×N matrix. Sum of each column. Gives a 1×N vector
G!     % Push input transposed
s      % Sum of each column. Gives a 1×N vector
v      % Concatenate vertically. Gives a 2×N matrix
!      % Transpose. N×2
100=   % Does each entry equal 100?
XA     % True for columns that contain only "true". Gives 1×2 vector. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Man that 100 was expensive, good answer though.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
AllTrue[#==100&]/@Apply[Plus,{#,#},{1}]&
```

As with other answers, the outputs are

`{False, False}` for non-stochastic

`{True, False}` for left-stochastic

`{False, True}` for right-stochastic

`{True, True}` for doubly stochastic

Saved 3 bytes by switching to the operator form of `AllTrue`

Comment: Use U+F3C7 (private use) for `\[Transpose]`

Comment: I considered it but thought that `�` was less enlightening

Comment: Also there's an extra `@` at the end

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <s>205</s> <s>203</s> 183 bytes

Golfed:

```
int F(int[,]m){int x,i,j,r,c,e,w;x=m.GetLength(0);e=w=1;for(i=0;i<x;i++){r=c=0;for(j=0;j<x;j++){r+=m[i,j];c+=m[j,i];}if(r!=100)e=0;if(c!=100)w=0;}return e==1&&w==1?3:e==1?1:w==1?2:4;}
```

Ungolfed with comments:

```
    int F(int[,] m)
    {
        //x - matrix size
        //i, j - loop control variables
        //r, c - row/column sum
        //e, w - east/west, pseudo-bool values indicate right/left stochastic
        int x, i, j, r, c, e, w;
        x = m.GetLength(0);
        e = w = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            r = c = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
            {
                r += m[i, j];
                c += m[j, i];
            }

            if (r != 100)
                e = 0;

            if (c != 100)
                w = 0;
        }

        return e == 1 && w == 1 ? 3 : e == 1 ? 1 : w == 1 ? 2 : 4;
    }
```

Output key:
1 - right stochastic
2 - left stochastic
3 - double stochastic
4 - none

Try it: http://rextester.com/PKYS11433

EDIT1: `r=0;c=0;` => `r=c=0;`

EDIT2: Nested ternary operators. Credits goes to @Yodle.

Comment: `if(e==1&&w==1)return 3;if(e==1)return 1;return w==1?2:4;` Since `e` and `w` can only be 1 or 0, it can be changed to `return w<<1|e;` and redefine none==0.

Comment: You can shorten yours by 30 if you turn some of those `if` statements into ternary operations and just return an integer at the end.  Idunno if I should post my solution since it's so similar.

Comment: @LinkNg Very nice. I don't want to write code without understanding. I'm not familiar with binary operators.

Comment: @Yodle Thank you, I changed my solution. Feel free to post your even if it is very similar.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 104 bytes

```
function($a){for($s=array_sum;$a[+$i];)$o|=$s($a[+$i])!=100|($s(array_column($a,+$i++))!=100)*2;echo$o;}
```

An anonymous function that echos 0 => both, 1=> left, 2=> right, 3=> neither.
Use like:

```
php -r "$c=function($a){for($s=array_sum;$a[+$i];)$o|=$s($a[+$i])!=100|($s(array_column($a,+$i++))!=100)*2;echo$o;};$c(json_decode($argv[1]));" "[[4,8,15],[16,23,42],[80,69,43]]"
```

A command line program version at 114 bytes:

```
for($a=json_decode($argv[1]);$a[+$i];)$o|=($s=array_sum)($a[+$i])!=100|($s(array_column($a,+$i++))!=100)*2;echo$o;
```

Used like:

```
 php -r "for($a=json_decode($argv[1]);$a[+$i];)$o|=($s=array_sum)($a[+$i])!=100|($s(array_column($a,+$i++))!=100)*2;echo$o;" "[[4,8,15],[16,23,42],[80,69,43]]"
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>70</s> 64 Bytes

Nothing crazy here, just making use of splatting in `zip` to transpose the matrix :) The outputs are as follows:

```
0 - not stochastic
1 - right stochastic
2 - left stochastic
3 - doubly stochastic
```

And here's the code :)

```py
k=lambda m:all(sum(x)==100for x in m)
lambda n:k(n)+2*k(zip(*n))
```

Comment: Is the star in (*n a mistake?

Comment: @hhh No, that's the `splat` operator :) Essentially that's what is letting me transpose the matrix :)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

```
a=>[a.some(a=>a.reduce((l,r)=>l-r,100)),a.some((_,i)=>a.reduce((l,a)=>l-a[i],100))]
```

Just to be contrary, not only does this output the right stoachistic result on the left, but the booleans are also inverted, so an output of `[false, true]` still means right stoachistic.

Answer (score 3):

### C#6, 130 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;bool[]F(int[][]a)=>new[]{a.Where((_,i)=>a.Select(x=>x[i]).Sum()==100).Count()==a.Length,a.All(x=>x.Sum()==100)};
```

`{False, False}` for non-stochastic
`{True, False}` for left-stochastic
`{False, True}` for right-stochastic
`{True, True}` for doubly stochastic

[repl.it demo](https://repl.it/E2PR/0)

Ungolfed

```cs
bool[]F(int[][]a)=>
    // Return new array of two bools. Array type is inferred from arguments
    new[]
    {
        // Left:
        // Count the no. of columns which sums up to 100
        a.Where((_,i)=>a.Select(x=>x[i]).Sum()==100).Count()
            // Then check if no. of such columns equal to total column count
            ==a.Length,
        // Right: Do all rows sum up to 100?
        // Can't use this trick for left because no overload of All() accept Func<TSource,int,bool> like Where() does
        a.All(x=>x.Sum()==100)
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, 57

```
{a={it.every{it.sum()==100}};[a(it),a(it.transpose())]}​
```

### Output

`[0,0]` if neither.

`[1,0]` if right.

`[0,1]` if left.

`[1,1]` if both.

Answer (score 3):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 17 bytes

In an unexpected twist, this submission is a function.

```
{[h]=UQ$+_M[Zaa]}
```

Returns a list of two `0`/`1` values: `[0 0]` = not stochastic, `[0 1]` = left stochastic, `[1 0]` = right stochastic, `[1 1]` = doubly stochastic. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=KAoge1toXT1VUSQrX01bWmFhXX0KIFtbOTkgMV1bMiA5OF1dCik&input=)

#### Explanation

```
{               }  A function:
              a    Function argument (nested list)
           [Za ]   Create a list containing a's transpose and a
          M        Map this function to each of the above:
       $+_           Sum down the columns
     UQ              Get unique elements
 [h]=                If stochastic, the result should be [100]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

[`{∧/100=+/↑⍵(⍉⍵)}`](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2227/100%3D+/%u2191%u2375%28%u2349%u2375%29%7D%20%A8%20%28%u236A100%29%20%28%u236A42%29%20%28%u2191%28100%200%29%280%20100%29%29%20%28%u2191%284%208%2015%29%2816%2023%2042%29%2880%2069%2043%29%29%20%28%u2191%2899%201%29%282%2098%29%29%20%284%204%u23741+%u237316%29&run)

`{ }` direct function definition (aka "dfn"), `⍵` is the argument

`⍵(⍉⍵)` the matrix alongside its transposition

`↑` mix them into a single 2×n×n array

`+/` sum along last axis, get a 2×n matrix

`100=` which elements are 100 (booleans are 0 1)

`∧/` "and"-reduction along last axis, get 2 booleans for left,right stochastic

Answer (score 2):

## C++14, <s>139</s> <s>136</s> <s>133</s> 130 bytes

-3 bytes for `s=M.size()`, -3 bytes for returning by reference parameter, -3 bytes as a unnamed lambda

```c++
[](auto M,int&r){int a,b,i,j,s=M.size();r=3;for(i=-1;++i<s;){for(j=-1,a=b=0;++j<s;a+=M[i][j],b+=M[j][i]);r&=(a==100)+2*(b==100);}}
```

Assumes input to be like `vector<vector<int>>`. Returns 3,2,1,0 for doubly, left, right, none stochastic.

Ungolfed:

```c++
auto f=
[](auto M, int& r){
  int a,b,i,j,s=M.size();
  r=3;
  for(i=-1;++i<s;){
    for(j=-1,a=b=0;++j<s;
      a+=M[i][j],
      b+=M[j][i]);
    r&=(a==100)+2*(b==100);
  }
}
;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/×=100/+∵⊟⍉.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAgL8OXPTEwMC8r4oi14oqf4o2JLgoKZiBbWzEwMF1dCmYgW1s0Ml1dCmYgW1swIDEwMF1bMTAwIDBdXQpmIFtbNCA4IDE1XVsxNiAyMyA0Ml1bODAgNjkgNDNdXQpmIFtbOTkgMV1bMiA5OF1dCmYg4oavNF80KzHih6ExNgo=)

-2 thanks to Bubbler

Returns `[0 0]` for neither, `[0 1]` for left stochastic, `[1 0]` for right stochastic, and `[1 1]` for both.

```
/×=100/+∵⊟⍉.
           .  # duplicate
          ⍉   # transpose
        ∵⊟    # elementwise couple
      /+      # sum
  =100        # where is it equal to 100?
/×            # product
```

Comment: 12 bytes: `/×=100/+∵⊟⍉.`

Comment: @Bubbler Fails for singleton arrays, unfortunately.

Comment: Singleton arrays should be input as `[[100]]`, not `[100]`.

Comment: @Bubbler Oops, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
,Z§ạȷ2§¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwhDgIxEAC/gkCO6La90j4FmkoMuQ9gMXgUFnXmPAF5FxK@cXykLDkSgtrN7Ozstm27r5XN0E33y/Nqh27o63h8nKbbefk69OtacxZjSmGRs7fzVIApZMPvREQaZRKwDjXJ0RAS3s1GSohCS4rfChY1lTUEVkTd1NGoIJ9/cYjXKhL@Eg5NvgE)

Outputs `[1, 1]` for doubly, `[0, 1]` for left, `[1, 0]` for right, and `[0, 0]` for neither.

```
,           Pair the input with
 Z          its transpose,
  §         sum the columns from each,
   ạ        take the absolute differences between each sum and
    ȷ2      1*10^2,
      §     sum each list of differences.
       ¬    Is each sum 0?
```

`,Z§=ȷ2P€` is perhaps more intuitive.